# Optimising CSV parsing to be faster

Tags: java, csv

I'm working on this "program" that reads data from 2 large csv files (line by line), compares an Array element from the files and, when a match is found, it writes my necessary data into a 3rd file. The only problem I have is that it is very slow. It reads 1-2 lines per second, which is extremely slow, considering I have millions of records. Any ideas on how could I make it faster? Here's my code:

```
     public class ReadWriteCsv {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    FileInputStream inputStream2 = null;
    Scanner sc = null;
    Scanner sc2 = null;
    String csvSeparator = ",";
    String line;
    String line2;
    String path = "D:/test1.csv";
    String path2 = "D:/test2.csv";
    String path3 = "D:/newResults.csv";
    String[] columns;
    String[] columns2;
    Boolean matchFound = false;
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path3);

    try {
        // specifies where to take the files from
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
        inputStream2 = new FileInputStream(path2);

        // creating scanners for files
        sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");

        // while there is another line available do:
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            count++;
            // storing the current line in the temporary variable "line"
            line = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Number of lines read so far: " + count);
            // defines the columns[] as the line being split by ","
            columns = line.split(",");
            inputStream2 = new FileInputStream(path2);
            sc2 = new Scanner(inputStream2, "UTF-8");

            // checks if there is a line available in File2 and goes in the
            // while loop, reading file2
            while (!matchFound && sc2.hasNextLine()) {
                line2 = sc2.nextLine();
                columns2 = line2.split(",");

                if (columns[3].equals(columns2[1])) {
                    matchFound = true;
                    builder.append(columns[3]).append(csvSeparator);
                    builder.append(columns[1]).append(csvSeparator);
                    builder.append(columns2[2]).append(csvSeparator);
                    builder.append(columns2[3]).append("\n");
                    String result = builder.toString();
                    writer.write(result);
                }

            }
            builder.setLength(0);
            sc2.close();
            matchFound = false;
        }

        if (sc.ioException() != null) {
            throw sc.ioException();

        }

    } finally {
        //then I close my inputStreams, scanners and writer
```

Comment: It looks like you're re-reading the entire second file for each line in the first.  *Of course* this is going to be slow for large files.

Comment: Can you fit both these files to memory? If so just read & load them to a data structure in memory (an array, a list, etc.). IO operations are *very* costly compared to memory ops.

Comment: @azurefrog how could I do it otherwise? new to programming, sorry -.-

Comment: @Yuri no, the files are too big

Comment: @Noobinator 1st, I would suggest highly that you sort each list.  

2nd, leverage the identities of sorted lists and file stream buffering to implementing a chunking program that will generate a value hash containing the existence of the columns[3] or columns2[1] value.

3rd, you should be able to quickly scan this hash to determine exactly which values match in both lists and write them to your output.

Answer (score 1):

Use an existing CSV library rather than rolling your own.  It will be far more robust than what you have now.

However, your problem is not CSV parsing speed, it that your algorithm is O(n^2), for each line in the first file, you need to scan the second file.  This kind of algorithm explodes very quickly with the size of data, when you have millions of rows, you'll run into problems.  You need a better algorithm.

The other problem is you are re-parsing the second file for every scan.  You should at least read it into an memory as an ArrayList or something first at the start of the program so you only need to load and parse it once.

Answer (score 0):

Use [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial)' CSV parser as it won't take much longer than a couple of seconds to process two files with 1 million rows each:

```
public void diff(File leftInput, File rightInput) {
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //many config options here, check the tutorial

    CsvParser leftParser = new CsvParser(settings);
    CsvParser rightParser = new CsvParser(settings);

    leftParser.beginParsing(leftInput);
    rightParser.beginParsing(rightInput);

    String[] left;
    String[] right;

    int row = 0;
    while ((left = leftParser.parseNext()) != null && (right = rightParser.parseNext()) != null) {
        row++;
        if (!Arrays.equals(left, right)) {
            System.out.println(row + ":\t" + Arrays.toString(left) + " != " + Arrays.toString(right));
        }
    }

    leftParser.stopParsing();
    rightParser.stopParsing();
}
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).